# Is Mutating a Data copy of a Prop object any better than mutating a prop? Why?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In the Vue docs there is a section on one-way data flow: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Here it explains that you should not mutate a prop. Additionally, it says:

> The prop is used to pass in an initial value; the child component wants to use it as a local data property afterwards. In this case, it’s best to define a local data property that uses the prop as its initial value:

At the bottom of this section, there is a note that says:

> Note that objects and arrays in JavaScript are passed by reference, so if the prop is an array or object, mutating the object or array itself inside the child component will affect parent state.

I’m considering the situation where you have a prop that is an object (or an array) and you have defined a local data property that uses the prop as its initial value:

```
props: {
        initialMyObject: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },

data() {
    return {
        myObject: this.initialMyObject
    }
}
```

If I mutate the data item `myObject`, since it is an object the prop itself will end up getting mutated. Is this therefore the same essentially as “mutating a prop” and to be avoided? Would it be preferable in this case to emit an event whenever a change to the object is desired (or to use Vuex)?

Thanks in advance for your help on this.

Comment: Correct. From a one-way data flow perspective, using an alias in the data is no better than mutating the same object via its prop name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply clone it though -

```
data() {
    return {
        myObject: {...this.initialMyObject}
    }
}
```

To avoid it.

But yeah you just can't reassign a value to a `prop`  as

It's just because `Object` is kind of reference memory. When you have Array or Object stored in any variable it's a reference variable.

Memory management in such case, The reference variable will points to a memory address in heap so you can add more n more value to address. However you cannot just replace that address with any new value even with the new address.

In my preference, You should prefer `Vuex`, whenever you want a value to get updated for whole project